Nginx seems to modify some of the HTTP headers, how to prevent that
I use the following settings for a reverse proxy.
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
            proxy_pass                 https://112.123.134.145:443;
            proxy_ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/cert.pem;
            proxy_ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/key.pem;
            proxy_ssl_verify           off;
        }
    }

When I transmit a request, I notice from the server side that some of the header fields are either modified or removed. I am still troubleshooting the root cause but I tend to believe it is Nginx that does the change, which includes:

"Connection: Keep-alive"  changed to  "Connection: Close"
"Authorization: Digest"   removed
"User-name: Myname"       removed

Note that the last one is a custom field that I create.
More specifically, this is the header sent in the request.
GET /uri
User-Agent: python-requests/2.32.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Authorization: Digest
User-Name: Myname
Content-Length: 119

This is the header received by the server.
GET /uri
Connection: close
Content-Length: 119

I want the header to reach server intact.
